# MVC Controls Toolkit DatePicker with Razor doesn't render Calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have tried following the documentation and examples of MVC Controls Toolkit to create a DatePicker but I can't get it to work.

I wonder if anyone can point me to what I am doing wrong please? Or provide a code example?
I am using Razor for my implementation with MVC3ControlsToolkit.dll...

```
@Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.Date, DateTime.Now);
```

---

I've updated my code to the one below, I get an empty textbox but no calendar pops up if I click in the text box. The documentation is not clear to me although I read it a few times! Following the docs, I have created a reference to MVC3ControlsToolkit.dll, MVCControlToolkit.Controls.Core-2.2.0.js and MVCControlToolkit.Controls.Datetime-2.2.0.js.

I want to get a populated textbox with the date in DB (this works in the normal textbox, but not the calendar control yet!) and when I click in the textbox, I want the calendar control to show up.  When I select a date from the calendar, the selected date will be written to the textbox and the calendar will close.

```
@{ var DT = @Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.Date, DateTime.Now, dateInCalendar: true); }
       @DT.DateCalendar(
                    inLine: false,
                    calendarOptions: new CalendarOptions
                    {
                        ChangeYear = true,
                        ChangeMonth = true,

                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimeFor return an object that you can use for both data and time.

```
@Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.Date, DateTime.Now).Date()
```

should work.
or

```
@{
var DTS=Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.Date, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Then place date and time wherever you like with @DTS.Date() and @DTS.Time()
if you want a date picker:

```
@{
var DT = @Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.Date, DateTime.Now, dateInCalendar: true);
}
```

and then:

```
@DT.DateCalendar(
 inLine: false,
 calendarOptions: new CalendarOptions{
 ChangeYear = true,
 ChangeMonth = true,
 });
```

Please refer to the [examples in the documentation](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimeInput%20and%20DateRange%20attribute) for more details.